# How to upload file from another language like titanium ios app and java application to a c# webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, file-upload, titanium, arrays

Its going to a grt puzzle for me now a days. I have developed a product which is implemented using multiple languages such as a C# Windows app, Titanium iOS  app, and a Java application with a team of friends.

I am using a c# web service which is taking parameter of datatype `byte[]`. I have completed my work on windows app by adding it in service reference.

My Titanium team mate asked me to create some sample code for this web service without using service refrence directly by the url, but instead, either:

- Call it with soap or http post methods.
- Create a web sevice that they will use with titanium in a easy way
- Any other useful idea on how to use the same webservice with titanium

As titanium boy is fresher with titanium right now so I have to do something but I am also stuck and don't know how to suggest him something so I need help from your side.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you encode your binary data into a Base64 string and send it as such to your C# service. Since you're using SOAP, it would be a very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built in Titanium utilities to encode your data to base64:

```
// Encode your data
var data = Titanium.Utils.base64encode(dataToSendToWebService);
```

Now send it using a HTTPClient:

```
var postDataTOServer = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
         // If the service returns successfully : true, or false
         var isUserAllowed = this.responseText; 
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
        // Web service failed for some reason
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info('webservice failed with message : ' + e.error);
    }
});

// POST
postDataTOServer.open('POST', 'http://yoursite.com/aspwebservice');

// you may have to change the content type depending on your service
// but this is the correct type for binary data
postDataTOServer.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

// This does a POST to server
postDataTOServer.send(data);
```